# Validate amp client id

Tags: amp-html

I want  to validate the amp-client-id I get from amp-pages, but I can't find a definition of its structure except of what is written here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/client-id -

"If a Client ID is generated by an AMP page, the Client ID follows the AMP format (amp- followed by a randomly generated string)."

Does the client id has a length limitations? 
What is the exact regex for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no information about the length of the Client ID and the exact regex. Based from the documentation of [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#clientId), the unique identifier is a randomly generated string.

> **Fiel Name:**   `clientId`    **Value Type:**`text`   **Default
>   Value:** `Randomly Generated`
>
> **Example value:** `35009a79-1a05-49d7-b876-2b884d0f825b`

Comment: Thanks @jess , you are talking about google analytics cid, but I'm talking about amp-client-id, that is more like GCLID of google.
GCLID has a regex: /^[A-Za-z0-9_-]{20,120}$/

Comment: You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/client-id) and it is related to what I have mentioned about `clientID` field.